# Bash loop Through CSV but left last row value with newline

Tags: json, bash

I have case with loop. My task is to create json file with loop from csv data. Unfornunately when i generate field pk, the value is empty that make my json fault.This is the subset of my csv

```
table,pk
aaa,nik
aab,ida
aac,idb
aad,idc
aae,idd
aef,ide
...
```

This is my full code:

```
#!bin/bash
CSV_LIST="/xxx/table_lists.csv"
DATA=${CSV_LIST}

mkdir sqlconn 
cd sqlconn
cat ${DATA} |
while IFS=',' read table pk ; do
    PK= echo ${pk} | tr -d '\n'
    cat > ./sqlservercon_$table.json << EOF 
    {"name" :"sqlservercon_$table","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","topics":"$table",

...

,"pk.fields":" $PK","pk.mode":"record_value","destination.table.format":"db.dbo.$table","errors.tolerance":"all","flush.size":"10000"
}}

EOF

done
```

So the rendered result give me this:

```
    {"name" :"sqlservercon_XXX","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","topics":"XXX",...
,"pk.fields":" ","pk.mode":"record_value","destination.table.format":"XXX.XXX.XXX","errors.tolerance":"all","flush.size":"10000"
}}
```

but when i not edited my field pk

```
...,
"pk.fields":" $pk",
...
```

, it gives me wrong JSON file like this:

```
...,"pk.fields":" id
",...
```

Any helps are appreciated

**UPDATE**

When i check my csv using `cat -v table_lists.csv` the last column has ^M character that ruin the json file. But i still don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please, post a significant subset of your csv input file.

Comment: You may take advantage from [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/) and `sed -i "s/\r//g" ${FILE}`.

Comment: After performing a short test with your sample script it seems for me that the line `PK= echo ${pk} | tr -d '\n'` was intended to be `PK=$(echo ${pk} | tr -d '\n')`.

Comment: for removing new line try `dos2unix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after several check, beside wrong script that i have give in here, I investigate the CSV file. I download it directly from Spreadsheet Google, even it's give me .csv, but not encoded right for UNIX or Ubuntu as my development environment.

So i decided to do something like this manually:

1. From google spreadsheet, select all column that i want to use
2. Create an empty csv file
3. Copy paste the cells it into the .csv file
4. Change the "  "(double space) with ,

And for the loop one, because i want to curl it instead save the json, i do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CSV_LIST="/home/admin/kafka/main/config/tables/table_lists.csv"
DATA=${CSV_LIST}

 while IFS=',' read table pk; do

curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d'{"name" :"sqlservercon_'$table'","config":{...,...,"destination.table.format":"db.dbo.'$table'","errors.tolerance":"all",
"flush.size":"10000"
}}' | jq
done < ${DATA}
```

Answer (score 1):

In respect to the comments I gave, the following script were working

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/test

CSV_LIST="/home/test/tableList.csv"
DATA=${CSV_LIST}

# Prepare data file     
sed -i "s/\r//g" ${DATA}

# Added for debugging purpose
echo "Creating connection file in JSON for"

# Print file content from 2nd line only
tail --lines=+2 ${DATA} |
while IFS=',' read TABLE PK ; do

    # Added for debugging purpose
    echo "Table: ${TABLE} and PK: ${PK}"

    # Added missing $()
    PK_TRIMMED=$(echo ${PK} | tr -d '\n')

    cat > ./sqlservercon_${TABLE}.json << EOF
    {"name":"sqlservercon_${TABLE}","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","topics":"${TABLE}",...,"pk.fields":"${PK_TRIMMED}","pk.mode":"record_value","destination.table.format":"db.dbo.${TABLE}","errors.tolerance":"all","flush.size":"10000"}}
EOF

done
```